# What is this plant with large bright green hairy seed pods and small flowers?

Tags: identification, weeds

This popped up in the garden. I'm not sure what it is or whether or not I want to keep it. Can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: That is definitely  *Gomphocarpus physocarpus*.  The flowers are a good character too (though a bit difficult to see).  It won't persist unless you are in a warm zone (8 or above) without protection.  Though it may come back from seed.  Sort of weedy, but if you like it, keep it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a little hard to tell from the photo, but it looks to me like it is a type of milkweed called balloonplant:

https://monarchbutterflygarden.net/milkweed-plant-seed-resources/asclepias-physocarpa/

ETA: Depending on your location, this plant could be invasive. It is impossible to know whether it is a problem without knowing where you are. It is a milkweed, though, so offers the same benefits to monarchs as other plants in the milkweed family.

Comment: AKA Bishop's Balls and the Testicle Plant.